# LESS/CSS adding a second class to an input to override the width of the first class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I am using JQUERY to add two classes to an input element:

JQUERY:

```
.addClass('dollar_input survey_txtBx');
```

**Question:** The LESS/CSS is using the width set by .survey_txtBx which is set to 50px but I recently added the .dollar_input class to override the width and set it to 150px.

**Results:** In the browser when I test I see both classes but the dollar_input width attribute has a strike through it telling me the surbey_txtBx is supplying the width attribute.

CSS:

```
    .survey_txtBx{
            width: 50px;
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center !important;
            margin: 0 2px;
            border: 1px solid @light-gray_d20;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: cadetblue;
            .border-radiuses();
            &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            font-size: 12px;
            opacity: .75;
            }

            &::-moz-placeholder {
            font-size: 12px;
            opacity: .75;
            }

            &:-ms-input-placeholder {
            font-size: 12px;
            opacity: .75;
            }

            &:-moz-placeholder {
            font-size: 12px;
            opacity: .75;
            }

        &.input-validation-error {
                border-color: @red;
                &:focus {
                    border-color: @red;
                }
                &.warning{
                    border-color: @orange;
                    &:focus {
                        border-color: @orange;
                        }
                }
            }

        &.long{
            width: 450px;
            text-align: left !important;
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
        &.medium{
            width: 250px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 0 5px
        }

        &:focus{
            &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            opacity: 0;
            }

            &::-moz-placeholder {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            &:-ms-input-placeholder {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            &:-moz-placeholder {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    }   
}

.dollar_input{width:150px;}
```

**Question:** Should I set the dollar_input as a child class of the survey_txtBx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeing the trailing brace below `.survey_txtBx`:-

```
    .survey_txtBx { 
       ...
    }
}
.dollar_input { 
   ...
}
```

I assume `.survey_txtBx` is within another selector like so:-

```
#other-selector{
    .survey_txtBx { 
       ...
    }
}
.dollar_input { 
   ...
}
```

with that being the case, when the LESS is compiled it will create the following:-

```
#other-selector .survey_txtBx { width:50px; }
.dollar_input { width:150px; }
```

a simple fix is to move `.dollar_input` inline with `.survey_txtBx`:-

```
#other-selector{
    .survey_txtBx{
       width:50px;
       ....
    }
    .dollar_input{
       width:150px;
    }
}
```

This will make both the same weight with the last winning.

Comment: Thanks @BenG you caught that trailing bracket which threw me off because I thought I was putting dollar_input in the line but after but I was actually outside of it because of that last bracket...if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Impact through CSS:

```
.dollar_input.survey_txtBx {
  width: 150px;
}
```

This should be considered as last solution, but as a quick workaround `!important` should work to override.

```
.dollar_input {
   width: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: I also saw this as a possible solution. If I am unable to figure out what is going on I will consider this option. Thanks!

Comment: If the rest is pretty much set and you just need this to finish, look no further!

Comment: the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will use the style from the CSS definition that is most accurate or later in the file.

```
.classA {
    width: 100px;
}
.classB {
    width: 150px;
}
```

If you have element with `class="classA classB"` the `width` of the element will be `150px` (because the `classB` exists **after** classA [in the CSS definition, not inside the `class="..."` attribute]).

You can check this snippet:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.classA {
  background: blue;
}
.classB {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA classB">123</div>

<div class="classB classA">123</div>
```

A workaround (if you want to force a specific class over some other class) is to duplicate that classname:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.classA, .classA.classA {
  background: blue;
}
.classB {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA classB">123</div>
```

In the second example the background will be blue (because there is `.classA.classA` in the CSS definition.

Comment: Based on the CSS I provided I have the .dollar_input{width:150px;} set after the survey_txtBx but I am still getting the 50px width? I will clear my cache and reload the page just to verify my changes got picked up. But based on your answer shouldn't my code be working?

Comment: It should, but without actual looking at your html+css it's hard to say. btw, a voteup here will be nice :) you know.

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are applied to the same element and you can't control the order of the class names, the following should work

```
.survey_txtBx {
  width: 50px;

  &.dollar_input{
    width:150px;
  }
}
```